# React Native promise return undefined when it is not empty

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to get the sub quizzes and checking with console log shows that the information is there and it is correct. But when I try to `console.log(quizzes)` I get 3 promises. Trying to see the info in it returns undefined:
`quizzes[0].then(r => { console.log("r") })`
This is my code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const quizzes = await this.quizzes();
    await this.subQuizzes(quizzes);
  }

  quizzes = async () => {
    return await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("quiz")
      .where("parentId", "==", "")
      .get();
  };

  subQuizzes = async (quizzes) => {
    quizzes = quizzes.docs.map(async (quiz) => {
      const subQuiz = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("quiz")
        .where("parentId", "==", quiz.id)
        .get();

      subQuiz.docs.map((subQ) => {
        return { uid: quiz.id, ...quiz.data(), quizzes: subQ.data() };
      });
    });
    quizzes[0].then((r) => {
      console.log("RESULT", r);
    });
  };
```

How can retrieve the 3 object from these promises and where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: `async` functions always return a promise, that's basically the whole point of the keyword. And the promises inside `quizzes` have to resolve to `undefined` because that async function returns nothing. It looks to me that you misunderstand what the `map` method does too (the `subQuiz.docs.map(...) ` line creates a new array and simply throws it away without doing anything with it).

Comment: Simply adding a `return` in front of the aforementioned line would probably solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not return a proper value from you first map:

i assume you should do smth like this:

```
return subQuiz.docs.map((subQ) => {
  return { uid: quiz.id, ...quiz.data(), quizzes: subQ.data() };
});
```

To retrieve the 3 object from these promises you could use Promise.all method:

```
const subQuizzes = async (quizzes) => {
  const quizzes = await Promise.all(
    quizzes.docs.map(async (quiz) => {
      const subQuiz = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('quiz')
        .where('parentId', '==', quiz.id)
        .get();

      return subQuiz.docs.map((subQ) => {
        return { uid: quiz.id, ...quiz.data(), quizzes: subQ.data() };
      });
    })
  );
  console.log('RESULT', quizzes);
};
```